# HttpClient request succeeds with timeout defined, but hangs without

Tags: java, rest, timeout, apache-httpclient-4.x

I found a strange hack-y way to fix my code and I was wondering if anyone could explain why it works. I am writing code that communicates with a REST API to upload a video file split into multiple HTTP requests.

I was having a problem with one of my video part requests connecting, but never responding. The program uploads the video in five parts, but it would always hang on the third part of the five parts. I decided to add a request hard timeout to force the program to skip that hanging part. Well, magically after adding that timer, there is no more hangup!

Any ideas why this is the case? The request doesn't actually timeout, yet the addition of this code keeps my program chugging.

```
private void uploadParts(String assetId) throws IOException {
    //set up post request
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    String url = "";

    //prepare video
    File video = new File("files/video.mp4");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(video));

    int partMaxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[partMaxSize];
    double fileSize = video.length();
    System.out.println(fileSize);
    System.out.println(fileSize / partMaxSize);
    int parts = (int) Math.ceil(fileSize / partMaxSize);
    System.out.println(parts);

    for(int i = 1; i < parts+1; i++)    {
        String partNumber = i + "";
        System.out.println("part: " + partNumber);
        int partSize = (int) (i < parts ? partMaxSize : fileSize);
        fileSize -= partSize;
        int tmp = 0;
        tmp = bis.read(buffer);
        url = String.format("https://www.site.com/upload/multipart/%s/%s", assetId, partNumber);

        final HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(buffer));

        //Magical code start
        int hardTimeout = 5; // seconds
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (request != null) {
                    request.abort();
                }
            }
        };
        new Timer(true).schedule(task, hardTimeout * 1000);
        //Magical code end

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    }
    bis.close();
}
```

If i leave out the magical code section, my code hangs on the third part. If I include it, the program runs through fine.

Comment: is this piece "communicates with a REST API" implemented by you?

Comment: @MingtaoZhang The API is not mine, but this code is. Any ideas why adding timeout code would keep the program from hanging? Thanks.

Comment: after adding the magic, this line System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase()); has OK result?

Comment: Actually, the response is CREATED. Which just means the stream was successfully uploaded. Quick overview. My loop should loop through 5 put requests to upload my video file in 5 parts. Without the magic, the third part (https://www.site.com/upload/multipart/%s/3) never responds. With the magic, the upload succeeds. Maybe it has to do with a side effect of starting a Timer? Creates a new thread? Unlocks the system somehow...?

Comment: For your information, I am using this API. http://developers.cimediacloud.com/#multipart-http-create-and-upload

Comment: Thank you for your input. I figured out the problem. Turns out I need to close the connection on each iteration to make sure I don't exceed the max simultaneous connections at once. In other words, I needed to call request.closeConnection() at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer! Turns out HttpClient only allows a certain number of connections at a time. According to my code, the default maximum connections is 2. I needed to close each connection after they were complete and the upload ran fine.

Fixed code adds request connection release.

```
private void uploadParts(String assetId) throws IOException {
    //set up post request
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    String url = "";

    //prepare video
    File video = new File("files/video.mp4");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(video));

    int partMaxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 5;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[partMaxSize];
    double fileSize = video.length();
    System.out.println(fileSize);
    System.out.println(fileSize / partMaxSize);
    int parts = (int) Math.ceil(fileSize / partMaxSize);
    System.out.println(parts);

    for(int i = 1; i < parts+1; i++)    {
        String partNumber = i + "";
        System.out.println("part: " + partNumber);
        int partSize = (int) (i < parts ? partMaxSize : fileSize);
        fileSize -= partSize;
        int tmp = 0;
        tmp = bis.read(buffer);
        url = String.format("https://www.site.com/upload/multipart/%s/%s", assetId, partNumber);

        final HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(buffer));

        //Magical code start
        int hardTimeout = 5; // seconds
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (request != null) {
                    request.abort();
                }
            }
        };
        new Timer(true).schedule(task, hardTimeout * 1000);
        //Magical code end

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        request.releaseConnection();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    }
    bis.close();
}
```

The timer was working because it was closing my old connections after 10 seconds. Thank you for your input, guys.